# How to construct bottle large application

Tags: python, bottle

In Flask, I can call `blueprint` function to construct my app.

I want to do the following:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    admin/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        static/
        templates/
    home/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        static/
        templates/
    control_panel/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        static/
        templates/
    models.py
```

In bottle, how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

In each path use `app=bottle.defaultapp()`. In your main app import all routing functions.